# How to go to next record by date when you pull records by ID?

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, date

I have a table that has three fields.  Event ID, Name, Date.  My site pulls in records by event id but I would like the next button to go to the next record by date.  How can this be accomplished?  For example:

```
1 testing 11.1.2015
2 testing 11.3.2015
3 testing 11.2.2015
```

The link to the page pulls in event id like `www.testing.php?eventid=1`

But when I go to next I want it to go in date order not ID order. So it should go to event id 3. currently I have the code set up as below, how could I tweak it to use the date field?

```
$result5 = mysql_query("SELECT event_id FROM events group by event_id order by event_id DESC LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error()); 
            while ($row5 = mysql_fetch_array($result5))
        {
        $maxevent= $row5['event_id'];

    <script>
$(document).on("pageinit",function(){

  var pathname = $(location).attr('href');
  var leva = $('#next').attr("href");
  var prava = $('#prev').attr("href");
  var preva = $('#ret').attr("href");

  $("body").on("swiperight",function(){
    <!--alert("You swiped right!");-->
    location.href=prava;
  }); 
    $("body").on("swipeleft",function(){
    <!--alert("You swiped left!");-->
    location.href=leva;
  });
if(leva === undefined) { 
 window.location.href="eventviewmusack.php?eventid=<?php echo $maxevent;?>";
}  


});
</script>
```

Comment: why are you doing a group by with no aggregate functions? Because you like its treatment of it as a distinct ?

Comment: Presumably you are retrieving the date for the current record? So you can use that in your next query. Just do `WHERE eventdate > thedateforthecurrentevent ORDER BY eventdate ASC LIMIT 1` (pseudocode, replace as needed)

Comment: What if the first event by ID is the last one by date?

Comment: Then the empty result would be appropriate

Comment: Ordering by `date` instead of `id``will give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the query User ORDER BY Date ASC